# FormatException Was Unhandled in Visual Studio

Tags: ms-access, visual-studio-2012

Please help.
I am a beginner, and I am Trying to save to access from visual studio 2012, it is giving me "FormatException was ungandles".
It indicates the error to be on "i = .ExecuteNonQuery()". I thought the error was with "1 =", but even when I tried that particular line without the "i =" it still gives the same error.
In the end, it still doesn't save to the database.
Kindly help me check the code.

```
   Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim ms As New Memorystream()
    Dim arrimage() As Byte
    If (PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing) Then
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)
        arrimage = ms.GetBuffer
        ms.Close()

    End If

    With cmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO TextBox1(RegNum,Lname,Fname,Oname,Gender,Religion,DOB,Pno,Address,Country,SOorigin,LGA,Faculty,Dept,Level,Passport,Course1,Cource2,Cource3,Course4,Course5,Course6,Course7,Course9,Course10) VALUES(@a0,@a1,@a2,@a3,@a4,@a5,@a6,@a7,@a8,@a9,@a10,@a11,@a12,@a13,@a14,@a15,@a16,@a17,@a18,@a19,@a20,@a21,@a22,@a23,@a24,@a25)"
        .Parameters.Add("@a0", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a3", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a4", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox1.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a5", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox5.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a6", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a7", OleDbType.Integer).Value = TextBox6.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a8", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox7.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a9", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox8.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a10", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox9.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a11", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox10.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a12", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox2.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a13", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox3.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a14", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox4.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a15", OleDbType.Binary).Value = IIf(PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing, arrimage, DBNull.Value)
        .Parameters.Add("@a16", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox5.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a17", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox6.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a18", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox7.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a19", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox8.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a20", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox9.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a21", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox10.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a22", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox11.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a23", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox12.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a24", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox13.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@a25", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox14.Text
        i = .ExecuteNonQuery()
        .Dispose()
        If (i > 0) Then
            MsgBox("Saved Successful")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Replace the code that sets each parameter to use a known valid value rather than the value read from the UI. Do this for all parameters and check that it saves. Put the correct code back for each parameter in turn until it fails. Work out why that fails (null value where the column doesn't take a null, wrong type etc.). You might need to repeat for more than one parameter/column.

Comment: Your table name is most certainly not `TextBox1`.

Answer (score 0):

You will save the date *value*, not the display of this, so:

```
.Parameters.Add("@a6", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
```

Comment: It still throws the error. Please try and help me out.

Comment: It now says "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same." but from the look of things, they are the same. Please, what should I do?